# Android Studio: Ambiguous Method Call

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm creating a custom Matcher for running Espresso tests on a 3rd party ToggleSwitch. I want for Espresso to know which toggle is "selected" in these switches.

Android Studio is underlining in red part of the custom matcher class. The catch is, the project builds successfully and the test runs successfully.

I can't figure out

1. Why the Ambiguous Method Call Error is showing up
2. If there's a syntax error, why the build is successful.

Here is the code

```
import android.view.View;
import com.llollox.androidtoggleswitch.widgets.ToggleSwitch;
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.BoundedMatcher;

public class ToggleSwitchMatcher extends BoundedMatcher<View, ToggleSwitch> {

    private final int togglePos;

    static ToggleSwitchMatcher inPosition(int togglePos){
        return new ToggleSwitchMatcher(togglePos);
    }

    private ToggleSwitchMatcher(final int togglePos){
        super(ToggleSwitch.class);
        this.togglePos = togglePos;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(ToggleSwitch item) {
        return item.getCheckedPosition() == togglePos;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeMismatch(Object item, Description description) {
        super.describeMismatch(item, description);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with checked position:").appendValue(togglePos);
    }
}
```

The parenthesis in this line are underlined

```
    return item.getCheckedPosition() == togglePos;
```

And the error states:

> Ambiguous Method Call. Both getCheckedPosition() in ToggleSwitch and getCheckedPosition() in ToggleSwitch match

Comment: Try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` and then `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Comment: @PedroOliveira I tried those steps and no dice - same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in the [ToggleSwitch](https://github.com/llollox/Android-Toggle-Switch/blob/master/androidtoggleswitch/src/main/java/com/llollox/androidtoggleswitch/widgets/ToggleSwitch.kt) class. The class declares the property `var checkedPosition : Int? = null`, for which Kotlin will generate a getter and a setter with the names `getCheckedPosition` and `setCheckedPosition`. However, the class also declares functions with these names.

Let's examine the Kotlin bytecode to see why it compiles. The property compiles to:

```
public final getCheckedPosition()Ljava/lang/Integer;
@Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible
 L0
 LINENUMBER 12 L0
 ALOAD 0
 GETFIELD com/llollox/androidtoggleswitch/widgets/ToggleSwitch.checkedPosition : Ljava/lang/Integer;
 ARETURN
L1
 LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/llollox/androidtoggleswitch/widgets/ToggleSwitch; L0 L1 0
 MAXSTACK = 1
 MAXLOCALS = 1
```

While the getter compiles to:

```
public final getCheckedPosition()I
 L0
 LINENUMBER 43 L0
 ALOAD 0
 GETFIELD com/llollox/androidtoggleswitch/widgets/ToggleSwitch.checkedPosition : Ljava/lang/Integer;
 DUP
 IFNULL L1
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Integer.intValue ()I
 GOTO L2
L1
 POP
 ICONST_M1
L2
 IRETURN
L3
 LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/llollox/androidtoggleswitch/widgets/ToggleSwitch; L0 L3 0
 MAXSTACK = 2
 MAXLOCALS = 1
```

The method signatures differ because of the return types, so the JVM accepts both methods, but to the caller it's ambiguous.

The class should instead move the getter and setter functionality to the `get()` and `set()` declarations of the property.

Comment: didn't expect it to be a `Kotlin` class... with broken interoperability. but this appears likely.

Comment: Thank you very much. I reached out to the creator of the library

Comment: @user1114 How? Issues over GitHub seems to be disabled, and his personal domain too.

Comment: There's a Get In Touch link at the bottom of the ReadMe in the repo. That being said I was not able to get in touch.

Answer (score 1):

removing the ambiguous getter from class `ToggleSwitch.kt` should make it work as expected:

```
fun getCheckedPosition() : Int {
    return checkedPosition ?: -1
}
```

Comment: @user1114 how could an explicit cast ever be ambiguous? it isn't even ambiguous, while there is only one class `ToggleSwitch` (assuming you've provided all the imports).

Comment: Beats me - I'm at a loss as to why the compiler thinks it's ambiguous